# Constructor Call must be the first statement in a constructor while using super();

Tags: java, android, constructor

what is the replacement of this super(); statement in my code ...because its showing me an error called:
Constructor Call must be the first statement in a constructor.

```
class c
implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
{

final b a;
private final Dialog b;

c(b b1, Dialog dialog)
 {
    a = b1;
    b = dialog;
    **super();**//Error Constructor Call must be the first statement in a constructor
 }

public void onClick(View view)
{
    b.cancel();
 }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, Java class name starts with Capital letter.

Comment: You've got your answer now, but it's worth taking a step back and trying to consider why you couldn't figure this out on your own. The compiler is telling you *exactly* what's wrong here. Your `super();` call is the third statement in your constructor, and as the compiler tells you, it has to be the first statement - so why didn't you just *make* it the first statement?

Comment: Also it's worth noting that you don't have to call `super()`. If you don't, the compiler will do it for you. You only have to do it explicitly if you want to call some other super constructor than the no argument version.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
 c(b b1, Dialog dialog) {
    super();
    a = b1;
    b = dialog;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change c to this:

```
c(b b1, Dialog dialog) {
  super();
  a = b1;
  b = dialog;
}
```

If you call the superclass constructor, you always have to do that before doing your own initialization.

Comment: The last sentence is a bit misleading. You don't always explicitly have to call the superclass constructor, but if you do, it must be the first statement.

Comment: Right, I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also for convenience change variable names like:

```
class C implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    final B a;
    private final Dialog b;

    c(B a, Dialog b) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        b.cancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`super();` refers to the extended class constructor i.e. `Object`..

To avoid getting such error,modify your code such that `super();` should be the first statement in constructor of `c` class.

```
c(b b1,Dialog dialog) 
{
    super();
    a = b1;
    b = dialog;
 }
```

P.S. Your compiler itself giving you the answer.